# how does librarys work in a django hosted website?

Tags: python, django, module

I never actually hosted any of my Django projects, so i'm with suspicious that the:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

That i do inside my viwes.py will not be so simple to do in a real hosted Django web page. When i run a local server, it works because i have theses modules installed in my pc, right? In a hosted website i will need something more than theses mere 3 line of code(like downloading the modules .py files)???

Comment: you don't host a django web page, you (or someone) host a server that runs a django application - dependencies and all

Comment: then, if i pay for host services and give the folder of the project to it that has modules that is importing librarys such numpy, pandas and other with simples: ' import numpy ' or 'import pandas' the server will run all the functions inside that librarys?

Comment: No, you need to install all the dependencies yourself in whatever way the provider supports